# I want to inject an executable into other executable

Tags: c#, file, executable, inject

Please Help me! I am a C# Programmer.Not very experienced.I want to inject an executable file into another executable file.Such that if I open this compound file first file will be executed then after its execution second file will be executed.How I do this?

Comment: Why can't you just launch the second .exe from the first with something like `Process.Start()`?

Comment: Do you have the **SOURCE CODE** for either of these executable files?  Or are you trying to accomplish this "task" (by presumably combining files, which isn't how things work) using C# as your medium?  ...or are you wanting to create a **THIRD EXECUTABLE**, written in C#, that launches the first app, waits for it to exit, then launches the second?

Comment: No I want one executable that is compound of two executables.I want to inject it like virus injects itself in .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use System.Diagnostics.Process class, for example :

```
Process SecondApp = Process.start(pathToExeFile);
```

Or, something like

```
ProcessStartInfo myInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
myInfo.FileName = pathToExeFile;
myInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExeFile);
myInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process SecondProcess = Process.Start(myInfo);
```

By the way, new processes do not block your current thread.

P.S Don't forget to add

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: you mean in a well "new process", more technically `Process.Start` doesn't block the current thread

Comment: I Appreciate your help but i want to inject one .exe file in other like virus injects itself in another .exe file.And I know all these Function.I am not a beginner.